# Exibir retorno de uma consulta SQL no Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, microsoft-excel

Minha pergunta é dividida em duas partes. A primeira, é possível realizar comando SQL pelo Excel, pois preciso exibir determinadas informações do meu Banco MySQL em uma tabela no Excel.

**Observação:** Não quero conexão via ODBC, preciso que seja realizada a consulta via comando SQL mesmo.

E a outra parte da pergunta, se for possível realizar o comando SQL, onde eu realizo ele?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia,

*é possível realizar comando SQL pelo Excel* ==> Sim, através do Microsoft Query. Veja na Faixa de Opções, grupo Dados, conexões de outras fontes, do Microsoft Query.

*se for possível realizar o comando SQL, onde eu realizo ele?* ==> Dentro do Microsoft Query. Você pode editar a Consulta SQL diretamente no botão "SQL" da barra de ferramentas. Você também pode salvar as consultas SQL em arquivos ".qdy" para executa-las com mais agilidade.

Sobre a observação: sim, você precisa do Driver ODBC do MySQL.

Comment: E só uma dúvida, eu consigo colocar valores de um campo da tabela do excel nessas *Querys*?

Comment: Olha eu nunca fiz isso, mas parece que sim, veja em https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-a-parameter-query-addf7cb7-ddf0-442f-a60c-cd7280e201bd (aplica-se ao Excel 2007)